# error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<std::counting_semaphore<1>, 4>’

Tags: c++, c++20, initializer-list, stdarray, binary-semaphore

The below code snippet does not compile. I tried different initializers but could not make it compile.

```
#include <array>
#include <semaphore>


int main()
{
    std::array<std::binary_semaphore, 4> semaphores { {0}, {0}, {0}, {0} };
    auto& [ lock1, lock2, lock3, lock4 ] { semaphores };
}
```

Here's the error message:

```bash
SO.cpp:8:74: error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<std::counting_semaphore<1>, 4>’
    8 |     std::array<std::binary_semaphore, 4> semaphores { {0}, {0}, {0}, {0} };
      |                                                                          ^
```

Isn't it possible to declare an array of `binary_semaphore`s? What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you could write for example adding one more pair of braces like

```
std::array<std::binary_semaphore, 4> semaphores { { {0}, {0}, {0}, {0} } };
```

Otherwise the first initializer `{0}` is considered as an initializer of the whole object of the std::array type.

However there is another problem. The constructor is explicit.

```
constexpr explicit counting_semaphore(ptrdiff_t desired);
```

So you need to use the explicit constructor in the initializers.

For example

```
    std::array<std::binary_semaphore, 4> semaphores 
    { 
        { 
            std::binary_semaphore{ 0 }, 
            std::binary_semaphore{ 0 }, 
            std::binary_semaphore{ 0 }, 
            std::binary_semaphore{ 0 } 
        }
    };
```

In this case you may also write without introducing the additional braces like

```
    std::array<std::binary_semaphore, 4> semaphores 
    { 
            std::binary_semaphore{ 0 }, 
            std::binary_semaphore{ 0 }, 
            std::binary_semaphore{ 0 }, 
            std::binary_semaphore{ 0 } 
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is related to the `explicit` constructor for `std::binary_semaphore`.

The below code compiles:

```
#include <array>
#include <semaphore>


int main()
{
    std::array<std::binary_semaphore, 4> semaphores { std::binary_semaphore { 0 }, std::binary_semaphore { 0 },
                                                      std::binary_semaphore { 0 }, std::binary_semaphore { 0 } };
    auto& [ lock1, lock2, lock3, lock4 ] { semaphores };
}
```

It doesn't look neat though.

Comment: You can reduce the noise by making use of CTAD, i.e. `std::array semaphores` rather than `std::array<std::binary_semaphore, 4> semaphores`.

Comment: @ildjarn Oh, nice. It's a good choice in this case. It didn't come to my mind.